# jijna2 for loop variable preservation?

Tags: python, html, web-applications, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a web app and trying to add functionality where you make an anonymous post and then someone can add an answer to it. I'm using Flask for backend. I have the posts stored in an SQLAlchemy database. By default, a post doesn't have an answer. To dispay the posts, I just print each one with a for loop using jinja2. In that for loop, I also print an "answer" button after each post that brings up a Foundation modal that is supposed to let the user enter their answer. The problem is that the `action` attribute references the post ID (`{{post.id}}`), which by the end of the loop refers to the last post. Here's my code:

```
{% for post in s: %}
  {% if post.nh == hood %}
    <li>
      <td> {{ post.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }} </td>
      <br>
      <td> {{ post.text }} {{post.nh}} </td>
      <br>
      <a href="" data-reveal-id="reply_modal" class="button tiny">Answer</a>
      <div id="reply_modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
        <form action='/{{post.id}}/{{hood}}' method="post"> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              <textarea placeholder="Write your answer here"name="user_input" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </form> 
        <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
      </div>    
      <br>
      {% if post.answer != 'none' %}
        <li>
          <div align="right">
            <td> {{ post.answer }} </td>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I basically need to preserve `{{post.id}}` for each "answer" button so that the answer gets added to the correct post. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `post.id` is the ID of each post in succession; the way you have done it, you will have one form for each post, and each one will reference the id of that post. Is that not what you want?

Comment: That's what I want, but that's not what it's doing. No matter which answer button I press, the answer gets added only to the last post. I'm assuming it's because `{{post.id}}` at the end of the `for` loop is the last post's id.

Comment: No, that's not it. Much more likely is that there is something wrong with your markup; seems like you're giving every form the same id attribute, which isn't valid in HTML, so that the JS just triggers the last form. Really, you shouldn't actually be outputting multiple forms anyway; you should be outputting a single one at the end, and passing the correct ID to it when it is displayed.

Comment: But how could I place the `form` outside of the `for` loop? If I did, `{{post}}` would be outside of its scope.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround by giving each form a unique id. Thanks for pointing out the bug!